# Why isn't my if/else if statement working?

Tags: java

I've looked at all the other similar threads here, and I still can't figure out why my program only prints A or A- no matter what. Please explain what I did wrong and how to change it. Thanks!

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grading 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int grade;
        out.println("Please enter your grade to be evaluated: ");
        grade = sc.nextInt();

        if(grade >= 93)
            out.println("A");
        else if(grade >= 90 && grade <= 92)
            out.println("A-");
        else if(grade >= 87 && grade <= 89)
            out.println("B+");
        else if(grade >= 83 && grade <= 86)
            out.println("B");
        else if(grade >= 80 && grade <= 82)
            out.println("B-");
        else if(grade >= 77 && grade <= 79)
            out.println("C+");
        else if(grade > =73 && grade <= 76)
            out.println("C");
        else if(grade >= 70 && grade <= 72)
            out.println("C-");
        else if(grade >= 67 && grade <= 69)
            out.println("D+");
        else if(grade >= 63 && grade <= 66)
            out.println("D");
        else if(grade >= 60 && grade <= 62)
            out.println("D-");
        else if(grade < 60)
            out.println("F");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me after fixing `else if(grade > =73` to `else if(grade >=73`.

Comment: Small correction for grade C condition: space before `=` sign `if(grade > =73 && grade <= 76)`. Other than that, it is working for me.

Comment: There is a space in `> =` on the line that should read `else if(grade >=73 && grade <= 76)`. Otherwise, it should be okay.

Comment: Since your code does not compile or run as posted, chances are that you're ignoring some error and running an old or different version of your program.

Comment: Thanks guys just realized there was a space thanks for helping out!

Comment: What happened is you had a working program that only output `A` and `A-`, then you added more code -- but that code had a syntax error and wouldn't compile, so you were running the old program. Be sure you watch for compiler errors before running your program!

Answer (score 2):

Your program works just fine. Just change

```
else if(grade > =73 && grade <= 76)
```

to

```
else if(grade >=73 && grade <= 76)
```